# .net: A class used in the expression is not loaded during debugging session

Tags: vb.net, debugging, debug-symbols

I have a strange issue here and need some help.
There is a Visual Studio 2010 Solution with several vb.net Projects.

Lets call them Project A, Project B and Project C

Project A and Project B use stuff from Project C.
Project A is the startup project.

When I start my programm, in Project A I can debug anything without any issues.
When there is a call from Project A to an Object defined in Project B, then 
I can not debug anything from Project C.
Following issues:

- when I want the debugger to step into a function in Project C,it will not do that.
- when I want to check a variable in locals or Watch, I get the message: "A class used in the expression is not loaded during debugging session" or "Cannot find the method on the object instance"

But when I manually put a breakpoint there, it will work. 
And Debugger then also works well for Project C and shows me all symbols.

so in summary: 
Debugger does not work when I try to debug/access functions and variables in Project C from
somehere in Project B.
From Project A it works without any issues.

I tried a lot of things so far without any result. Any ideas what goes wrong here?
Thanks in Advance!

**UPDATE**: Maybe I should mention that Projects A,B,C have also other dependencies, f.e. references to other projects.

Comment: Have you checked the `Modules` window to see if the symbols are loaded for Module C?

Comment: yeah, modules are loaded. But for some reason, I can see that some Modules are loaded twice!? If there is a module called blablub, there is an entry "blablub" and an entry "blablub.dll". Is that normal? Can it be related?

Comment: This is a [documented issue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983385%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for VB.NET.  You'll have to live with it if you can't follow the guidance in the MSDN article.

Comment: this is a really old articles and it is about Visual Studio 2005. 
But even if I follow the guidance in the article, it still doesn't work.
In fact, that was the first thing I tried, since it was the first google match ;).